# Images are not visible during flutter_driver tests

Tags: flutter, flutter-test

When running UI tests with flutter driver the assets are not displayed on iPhone simulator. They are displayed when app is run in debug mode from VS Code.

I tried to reproduce it on the example project generated by `flutter create -i swift -a kotlin --androidx --org com.example example` but without success. I followed exactly the same process of introducing flutter_driver tests in both apps according to this article. Unfortunately, in my app the images are not shown, and in example app they appear just fine. I compared project.pbxproj and pubspec.yaml files and they look fine to me.

For instance my pubspec.yaml:

```
dev_dependencies:
  flutter_driver:
    sdk: flutter
  test: any
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  screenshots:

flutter:
  uses-material-design: true

  assets:
    - assets/lang/pl.json
    - assets/images/
```

Is there anything that can help me with this issue? What can I do to debug the problem?

### Logs

Beware, this is a very long log output.

`flutter drive --target=test_driver/app.dart --verbose`

https://gist.github.com/orestesgaolin/861c4f191773ca152b400d97ced2daeb

### Flutter doctor

`flutter doctor -v`

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.7.8+hotfix.4, on Mac OS X 10.14.6 18G87, locale pl-PL)
    • Flutter version 1.7.8+hotfix.4 at /Users/dominik/Library/flutter
    • Framework revision 20e59316b8 (6 weeks ago), 2019-07-18 20:04:33 -0700
    • Engine revision fee001c93f
    • Dart version 2.4.0


[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 28.0.3)
    • Android SDK at /Users/dominik/Library/Android/sdk
    • Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling support)
    • Platform android-28, build-tools 28.0.3
    • ANDROID_SDK_ROOT = /Users/dominik/Library/Android/sdk
    • Java binary at: /Users/dominik/Library/Application Support/JetBrains/Toolbox/apps/AndroidStudio/ch-0/191.5791312/Android
      Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_202-release-1483-b49-5587405)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 10.3)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Xcode 10.3, Build version 10G8
    • CocoaPods version 1.7.5

[✓] iOS tools - develop for iOS devices
    • ios-deploy 1.9.4

[✓] Android Studio (version 3.5)
    • Android Studio at /Users/dominik/Library/Application Support/JetBrains/Toolbox/apps/AndroidStudio/ch-0/191.5791312/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin version 37.1.1
    • Dart plugin version 183.6270
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_202-release-1483-b49-5587405)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.37.1)
    • VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
    • Flutter extension version 3.3.0

[✓] Connected device (1 available)
    • iPhone Xs Max • C1A5534A-AE3A-4FB3-95F6-993E351FF2D3 • ios • com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-12-4 (simulator)

• No issues found!
```

Comment: Thanks for this question, I'm having the same issue with a *.json!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

So the solution was to create separate `main_test.dart` file that wraps whole app in `DefaultAssetBundle` like so:

```
runApp(DefaultAssetBundle(
      bundle: TestAssetBundle(),
      child: App(),
    ));
```

and `TestAssetBundle` is like so:

```
class TestAssetBundle extends CachingAssetBundle {
  @override
  Future<String> loadString(String key, {bool cache = true}) async {
    final ByteData data = await load(key);
    if (data == null) throw FlutterError('Unable to load asset');
    return utf8.decode(data.buffer.asUint8List());
  }

  @override
  Future<ByteData> load(String key) async => rootBundle.load(key);
}
```

And in `app.dart` you have to reference correct file:

```
import 'package:flutter_driver/driver_extension.dart';
import 'package:playoo_league_player/main_test.dart' as app;

void main() {
  // This line enables the extension.
  enableFlutterDriverExtension();

  // Call the `main()` function of the app, or call `runApp` with
  // any widget you are interested in testing.
  app.main();
}
```

Full explanation can be found here: https://medium.com/@sardox.vl/flutter-test-and-randomly-missing-assets-in-goldens-ea959cdd336a

Comment: Is there any reason you created to create a main_test.dart file? I just used your approach and put it into my regular main.dart file and everything seems to work out quite well?

Comment: I have dedicated `main_test.dart` file for UI tests (e.g. it turns on the _demo mode_ which doesn't require network connection and has some mock data). It's almost the same as `main.dart` but has some special flags enabled.

Answer (score 0):

```
Those Images are not loading because of cache issues .For that we can 
use  
PRE CACHE IMAGES to preload the images

class App extends StatefulWidget {
@override
State<App> createState() => _AppState();
}

class _AppState extends State<App>{ 

late image image1
late image image2


@override
void initState() {
super.initState();
image1 = Image.asset('assets/images/');
image2 = Image.asset('assets/images/');
}
@override
void didChangeDependencies() {

pre cacheImage(image1.image, context);
pre cacheImage(image2.image, context);
super.didChangeDependencies();
}
```

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Container
}

if it is multiple assets or images you can save this method as  class and
initialise it from main.dart .