# asset loading for flutter_driver tests

Tags: flutter, flutter-test

I followed the guidance from [Images are not visible during flutter_driver tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57712781/images-are-not-visible-during-flutter-driver-tests).

With this implementation I am getting the following using `screenshots` which calls `flutter driver`.

```
[VERBOSE-2:ui_dart_state.cc(148)] Unhandled Exception: inheritFromWidgetOfExactType(DefaultAssetBundle) or inheritFromElement() was called before MyAppState.initState() completed.
When an inherited widget changes, for example if the value of Theme.of() changes, its dependent widgets are rebuilt. If the dependent widget's reference to the inherited widget is in a constructor or an initState() method, then the rebuilt dependent widget will not reflect the changes in the inherited widget.
Typically references to inherited widgets should occur in widget build() methods. Alternatively, initialization based on inherited widgets can be placed in the didChangeDependencies method, which is called after initState and whenever the dependencies change thereafter.
#0      StatefulElement.inheritFromElement.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4164:9)
#1      StatefulElement.inheritFromElement (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4207:6)
#2      Element.inheritFromWidgetOfExactTyp<…>
```

On the target simulator (IOS) the screen just goes black with no content with or without the use of `CachingAssetBundle`.

The application runs fine with `flutter run`.  The application has a 25MB of data that is loaded via

```dart
String data = await DefaultAssetBundle.of(context).loadString(
        "assets/data/repeats.json",
        cache: false);
```

Answer (score -1):

This is resolved.  My app was doing the `loadString` of assets from inside of the main app `init_state()`.

This works fine for the app runtime, but does not work in the `flutter_driver` environment.

Comment: How was it resolved? Where did you load the string instead of "init_state()" to get it to work in flutter_driver environment?

Comment: I added a call in the `build()` function of main.dart which implements the `loadString` of the file.  I also have a variable in `initState()` that tracks if the file has been loaded.  I want to insure that the data is only loaded once.  IMHO the fact that this works in the app but not the test environment is a bug in the test system, but I have not filed it.